# Which Haskell compiler has informative (beginner-friendly) error messages?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I'm starting to learn Haskell and I've heard that many Haskell compilers have especially cryptic error messages.

Which compiler would be the best for a beginner learning the language?

Comment: This is pretty subjective. I'm not sure if you'll get good answers.

Comment: The error messages seem to make sense for me, however I am using ghci, with the "Real World Haskell" book, and I've only done the simple exercises (ie, still working through the book)

Comment: @Matthew: Do you have an example of a cyptic error?  To me, a cryptic error is one that does not contain the information needed to understand the error, and/or is entirely misleading.

Comment: Use the ghc. If you can't comprehend a message, paste it and the offending code on hpaste.org, and log in to #haskell at webchat.freenode.net

Comment: It takes time to gain an intuition for common errors that will arise whilst you are programming in a given language. You will eventually realize that you make certain errors a lot, and you will be able to find them quickly. If you don't understand the technical meaning of a certain error message, well google is your friend there.

Comment: [Helium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_(Haskell)) was created as a dialect of Haskell with simpler error messages. I recommend to use GHC instead.  Helium has no typeclasses, which are a very basic feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't get better error messages than with GHC and GHCi.

Historically, [Hugs](http://www.haskell.org/hugs/) was a Haskell compiler that was meant for teaching, and thus focused on error messages that were easy to understand for beginners. However it has seen very little development lately (no commits since January 2010). Also, nearly everyone uses GHC while developing with Haskell, so you get a bigger community with it.

Finally the Haskell platform is the easiest way of installing Haskell with some useful additional libraries—that also uses GHC.

So Hugs is no longer a very good choice for a beginner.

GHC's error messages are quite good, you just need to have a good grasp of the fundamentals of Haskell to understand them. You will quickly get that as you gain more experience.